# Regex remove drive letter & replace forward slashes with whitespace

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a Perl Regex replacement pattern which does the following:

Input: `C:/images/sample folder/any_sub-folder01/`
Output: `images sample folder any_sub-folder01`

So it should **trim the drive letter** and **replace any forward slash by a whitespace**.
Paths can contain any characters that are valid in Windows paths.

Probably it's a quite simple pattern, but I'm not very good at regular expressions..
Needs to be Perl regex for use in ExifTool - any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should post up what you've tried to help people troubleshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Remove drive letter:

```
s/^\w\://;
```

## Convert / to space:

```
s/\// /g;
```

Do you want to cut off the leading "/"? Use this RegEx as the first one:

```
s/^\w\:\///;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to combine these two in a single RegEx?

Comment: @Gino, No, there's no way to combine substitution operators into a regex.

Comment: ...You could combine the two substitution operators into one if they both replaced with the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
use Path::Class qw( file );

my @components = file($path)->components();
shift(@components);
my $display = join(' ', @components);
```

This handles all volumes (`\\foo\bar`), not just drives (`c:\`).

Answer (score 0):

Pasted from RegexPlanet:

Regular expression:     `(C:)?\/`

Options:    `g`

Perl regex object:  `qr/(C:)?\//`

Perl variable:  `(C:)?\/`

Now all you have to do is trim the leading and trailing white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can module Parse::Path to parse file path and name:

```
use v5.10;
use Parse::Path;

my $path = Parse::Path->new(
   path  => 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32',
   style => 'File::Win32',
);

say $path->as_string;
$path->push($path, 'DRIVERS');
say $path->as_string;

$path->volume('D');
say $path->as_string;

my $volume = $path->volume;
$path->volume('Z');
$path->volume('');  # removes the volume
```

Comment: However it looks nice I guess this isn't an option. Need the RegEx as input for ExifTool to insert the path as seperate words into the IPTC caption of some images.
exiftool "-iptc:caption-abstract<${directory;REGEX HERE}"